# Strange NDSolve Error in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to numerically solve a long list of ordinary differential equations using `NDSolve` as follows:

`sols = NDSolve[deqs, operons, {t, 0, 1000}];`

where `deqs` holds the list of differential equations and `operons` stores the list of functions.

My error is "NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument "

and a sample of the string of error code it gives me afterward is:

`acs'[t]==-0.04 acs[t]+(0.08Sin[0.01t]^4)/(1+Sin[<<1>>]^4), acs[0]==0, adaalkB'[t]==-0.04adaalkB[t]+0.08/(1+adaalkB[<<1>>]^2)`

where acs[t] and adaalkb[t] are two of the functions in the differential equation.

I have no idea what the <<2>> or the <<1>> means, so if anyone could help, that would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is probably better for http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: << ... >> is a `Skeleton` (search for it in the help system). It just means "there are omitted chars here"

Comment: How to tell mathematica to show full error message without omitted text and without <<1>>? I have the similar issue and I want to see whole error message.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own experience, I guess you have first(or somewhere else in the code) tried these equations with "=" instead of "==" which will set the variables.
Try one of the following, hopefully it should work:
-renaming all the variables in the NDSolve, to something which has not been used in your notebook before.
OR
-Killing the Kernels:
CloseKernels[];